# Create an ARIA role menu using HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, wai-aria

so I have the code setup already, but I'm not sure how to incorporate the tab/arrows so that it moves onto the sub menu.

Here is a jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/Fep5Q/60/

This is part of the HTML code I have:

```
<div role="navigation" aria-label="Main menu" id="menuwrapper">
<ul class="nav" role="menubar" aria-hidden="false">
   <li><a href="#">MENU 1</a>
        <ul role="menu">
            <li role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true"><a href="">TEST1</a></li>
            <li role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true">TEST2</a></li>
            <li role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true">TEST3</a></li>
            <li role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true">TEST4</a></li>
            <li role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true">TEST5</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your css , your li should be float left .

```
#menuwrapper ul, #menuwrapper ul li{
    float:left;
}
```

here is your solution .

```css
#menuwrapper ul, #menuwrapper ul li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
       float:left;
   
}

/* We apply background color and border bottom white and width to 150px */
#menuwrapper ul li{
    background-color:#7f95db;
    border-bottom:solid 1px white;
    width:150px;
    cursor:pointer;
  
}

/* We apply the background hover color when user hover the mouse over of the li component */
#menuwrapper ul li:hover{
    background-color:#6679e9;
    position:relative;
}

/* We apply the link style */
#menuwrapper ul li a{
    padding:5px 15px;
    color:#ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/**** SECOND LEVEL MENU ****/
/* We make the position to absolute for flyout menu and hidden the ul until the user hover the parent li item */
#menuwrapper ul li ul{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}

/* When user has hovered the li item, we show the ul list by applying display:block, note: 150px is the individual menu width.  */
#menuwrapper ul li:hover ul{
    left:150px;
    top:0px;
    display:block;
}

/* we apply different background color to 2nd level menu items*/
#menuwrapper ul li ul li{
    background-color:#cae25a;
}

/* We change the background color for the level 2 submenu when hovering the menu */
#menuwrapper ul li:hover ul li:hover{
    background-color:#b1b536;
}

/* We style the color of level 2 links */
#menuwrapper ul li ul li a{
    color:#454444;
    display:inline-block;
    width:120px;
}

/* Clear float */
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div role="navigation" aria-label="Main menu" id="menuwrapper">
 <ul class="nav" role="menubar" aria-hidden="false">
       <li><a href="#">MENU 1</a>
            <ul role="menu">
    <li role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true"><a href="">TEST1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST5</a></li>
            </ul> 
        <li><a href="#">MENU 2</a>
            <ul>
    <li><a href="">TEST1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">MENU 3</a>
            <ul>
    <li><a href="">TEST1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">MENU 4</a>
            <ul>
    <li><a href="">TEST1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST5</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#">MENU 5</a>
            <ul>
    <li><a href="">TEST1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST5</a></li>
            </ul> 
  </li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

see & modify however you like .